# Can't invoke git-svn from command line

Tags: git, git-svn

I just installed git on my linux machine (Kubuntu distro) by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core git-doc gitweb git-gui gitk git-email git-svn
```

I would like to migrate a project which currently uses subversion to git. But if I run git-svn I get the message : **git-svn: command not found**

Any way to fix this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 41):

The (new) interface to run `git-svn` is actually:

```
$ git svn <command> [options] [arguments]
```

(notice the lack of `-`)

Comment: should work both ways … old way was using hyphenated commands

Comment: knittl: obviously, the old way does not work on some installations

Comment: ok, you are right, i just tested this on my machine. `git-svn` doesn’t work, while `git svn` does. +1

Comment: The old command style `git-svn` was finally removed at version 1.6.0

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get install git-svn
```

This command does it all in Ubuntu. Your distro (example yum install) can probably do it.